# What is ".alert span" exactly?

Tags: css, meteor

I am using [This tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/uploading-files-to-amazon-s3/) as a reference, and I am trying to use the below piece of code in my project :

```
  let _setPlaceholderText = ( string = "Click or Drag a File Here to Upload" ) => {
      template.find( ".alert span" ).innerText = string;
    };
```

It works fine with the tutorial code when I download it and tested it, but when I copy pasted exact the same code to my project it didn't work.

If I am not mistaken the problem has to do with this line of code :

```
template.find( ".alert span" ).innerText = string;
```

can anyone explain for me what is ".alert span"? the tutorial says that the above line attempts to find the .alert span element only. Unfortunately, it wasn't enough for me to understand how to get it to work in my project.

Any help please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're looking at the inner text for a piece of CSS intended to modify the style of span elements contained within anything that has the class name alert.

It might looks like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .alert span {
        color: #ff0000;
    }
</style>
```

For modifying something like this:

```
<div class="alert">
    <span>There was an error!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand you, i have the css code he put in the tutorial, copy pasted it to my project, but didn't work as well

Comment: in the tutorial, he put the css code inside _upload.scss folder, i put it inside design.css and it didn't work, i tried to create the same folder extension as he did, when i do that, the css code is not even excuted